# Connection and notification in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) GATT Profiles

Tags: notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

As stated [here](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-328525), a BLE GATT client can "subscribe" to a specific characteristic in a GATT server to be notified each time a change occurs within this characteristic.

Actually I'm wondering, does the notifying characteristic keep alive the connexion between the client and the server during all the time of the "subscription" ? In other words, after having subscribed to the notifying characteristic, will the client and server remain connected until the client forces the deconnexion ?

Answer (score 1):

Subscription of notifications is not related to whether a client or server should keep a connection or disconnect. There is nothing in the specification that says so at least.

However an application can of course create custom rules such as the link should be disconnected if there are no subscriptions for some amount of time. The Windows BLE stack even does this per default.